# Understanding string constant \s! in ConTeXt typescript files

Tags: context

I'm trying to write my own typescript, and was advised to look at the ones provided in the ConTeXt distribution. They contain lines such as the following:

```
\definefontsynonym [\s!Serif] [\s!name:dejavuserif] [\s!features=\s!default,\s!fallbacks=\s!Serif]
```

I don't understand if and why the `\s!` parts are needed. The file `syst-aux.mkiv` says they are string variables, but then, where are those defined? What do they contain? Is `\s!name` the name of a variable that contains something, or is "name" the content?

If it's easily explained in a manual I must have missed it, and would appreciate if someone could either point me towards the explanation or just explain it to me in simple words. I just want to understand how to make a typescript to get a downloaded font working, I don't need to fully understand all the finer points of system macros.

Comment: You could use `Serif`. The `\s!`, `\c!`, `\v!` and other prefixes used by ConTeXt mean to define private macros in order to protect them and make them work with the multilingual interface. Not strictly needed, but very recommended